# Error while initializing actor system wavesplatform com.protonail.leveldb.jna.LevelDBException

Tags: scala, blockchain, wavesplatform

I want to fork the waves blockchain in which I wanted to change the coin. I first change the name of coin in waves node

link : [https://github.com/wavesplatform/Waves/blob/version-1.2.x/node/src/main/scala/com/wavesplatform/transaction/assets/exchange/AssetPair.scala](http://%20https://github.com/wavesplatform/Waves/blob/version-1.2.x/node/src/main/scala/com/wavesplatform/transaction/assets/exchange/AssetPair.scala)

according to the link I deployed on windows and I got this error.

**ERROR: 18:28:45,568 ERROR [main] c.w.actor.RootActorSystem$ - Error while initializing actor system wavesplatform com.protonail.leveldb.jna.LevelDBException: IO error: /root/.local/share/waves-testnet/data: Invalid argument**

(note : full error is given below)

software details:

1. openjdk11
2. ubuntu 18.04LTS

I am deploying in windows through ubuntu 18.04LTS by following steps for installing in windows and installing deb file.

link for installing: https://docs.waves.tech/en/waves-node/how-to-install-a-node/on-windows

**command: java -jar node/target/waves-all-1.2.15-DIRTY.jar node/target/classes/application.conf**

I got error while initializing it with wavesplatform.

```
root@WJLP-1220:/mnt/c/Users/swatim/Desktop/wavesProject/Waves/node/target# java -jar waves-all-1.2.15-DIRTY.jar classes/application.conf 
2021-01-04 18:28:44,524 INFO [main] c.w.Application$ - Starting... 
2021-01-04 18:28:45,082 INFO [ctor.default-dispatcher-4] a.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started 2021-01-04 18:28:45,193 INFO [main] c.w.Application$ - Waves v1.2.15-DIRTY Blockchain Id: T 
2021-01-04 18:28:45,271 INFO [main] c.w.d.LevelDBFactory$ - Loaded com.wavesplatform.database.jna.LevelDBJNADBFactory with com.wavesplatform.database.jna.LevelDBJNADBFactory@72ba28ee 
2021-01-04 18:28:45,568 ERROR [main] c.w.actor.RootActorSystem$ - Error while initializing actor system wavesplatform com.protonail.leveldb.jna.LevelDBException: IO error: /root/.local/share/waves-testnet/data: Invalid argument 
at com.protonail.leveldb.jna.LevelDBNative.checkError(LevelDBNative.java:295) 
at com.protonail.leveldb.jna.LevelDB.(LevelDB.java:16) at com.wavesplatform.database.jna.LevelDBJNADBFactory.openJnaDatabase(LevelDBJNADBFactory.scala:11) 
at com.wavesplatform.database.jna.LevelDBJNADBFactory.open(LevelDBJNADBFactory.scala:15) 
at com.wavesplatform.database.package$.openDB(package.scala:51) 
at com.wavesplatform.Application.(Application.scala:69) 
at com.wavesplatform.Application$.$anonfun$startNode$4(Application.scala:558) 
at com.wavesplatform.Application$.$anonfun$startNode$4$adapted(Application.scala:555) 
at com.wavesplatform.actor.RootActorSystem$.start(RootActorSystem.scala:25) 
at com.wavesplatform.Application$.startNode(Application.scala:555) 
at com.wavesplatform.Application$.main(Application.scala:524) 
at com.wavesplatform.Application.main(Application.scala)
```

Comment: please anyone help me with it.

Comment: Did you write any code to get that or just run the jar file?

Comment: @TomerShetah  after changing the coin name I tried to install deb file :  command: sudo dpkg -i *.deb. After installing it gave me the .jar file and i tried that jar file with application.conf